# Seed is wiping out existing data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a table with a fix number of rows, 51 one for every US state plus DC.  In addition to the StateCode column there is some per-state data as well.  But the number of rows will not change.

```
StateCode    DataColum1    DataColumn2   etc
```

---

When the db is seeded, I need to populate the table with the the 51 rows if they don't exist. But if they do, I need to leave the table alone.

The way I am currently doing it wipes out all the data every time I do a `database-update`.

```
context.StateLeadSettings.AddOrUpdate(s => s.StateCode,
    new StateLeadSettings() { StateCode = "AK" },
    ....
 );
```

Not sure how to change this so it only adds if they don't exist.

Comment: Here's a [good resource](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) on this.  Scroll down to the 'Enter Migrations' section.

Comment: Could this - [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604(v=vs.113).aspx) - be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
var stateLeadSettings = new List<StateLeadSettings>{
    new StateLeadSettings() { StateCode = "AK" },
    ....
};
var codes = stateLeadSettings.Select(x => x.StateCode).ToList();
var existed = context.StateLeadSettings.Where(x => codes.Contains(x.StateCode))
                .Select(x => x.StateCode).ToList();
context.StateLeadSettings.AddRange(stateLeadSettings
                .Where(x => !existed.Contains(x.StateCode)).ToList());
context.SaveChanges();
```